# Get previous row updated value using LAG Without using Recursive CTE

Tags: sql-server-2012, lag

How to use **LAG** function to get the updated previous row value (without using **Recursive CTE**). Please check the screenshot for sample output

[image]

**Query Tried**

```
 Declare @Tbl as Table(SNO Int,Credit Money,Debit Money,PaidDate Date)
Insert into @Tbl
SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1,0,12,'7Jan16'), (2,10,0,'6Jan16'), (3,15,0,'5Jan16'), (4,0,5,'4Jan16'), (5,0,3,'3Jan16'), (6,0,2,'2Jan16'), (7,20,0,'1Jan16')) AS X(SNO,Credit,Debit,PaidDate)

Select
    T.SNO,
    T.Credit,
    T.Debit,
    TotalDebit = Case When Credit < LAG(T.Debit, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY SNO) Then Debit + (LAG(T.Debit, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY SNO)-Credit) Else Debit End,
    Amount = Case When Credit < LAG(T.Debit, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY SNO) Then 0 Else Credit-LAG(T.Debit, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY SNO) End,
    T.PaidDate
From @Tbl T
```

### [image]

**UPDATE:**
Can get the expected result using recursive CTE, but when i convert the query to function and when i join the function with 3000 record, takes long time to execute. That's why i am trying to convert the query without recursive CTE part.

**Recursive CTE Query:**

```
Declare @Tbl as Table(SNO Int,Credit Money,Debit Money,PaidDate Date)
Insert into @Tbl
SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1,0,12,'7Jan16'), (2,10,0,'6Jan16'), (3,15,0,'5Jan16'), (4,0,5,'4Jan16'), (5,0,3,'3Jan16'), (6,0,2,'2Jan16'), (7,20,0,'1Jan16')) AS X(SNO,Credit,Debit,PaidDate)


;With Temp As(/* Detect Debited amount */
    Select Top 1 SNO,Credit,Debit,Debit As TotalDebit,Credit As Amount,PaidDate From @Tbl
    Union All
    Select
        R.SNO,
        R.Credit,
        R.Debit,
        TotalDebit = Case When R.Credit < RP.TotalDebit Then R.Debit + (RP.TotalDebit-R.Credit) Else R.Debit End,
        Amount = Case When R.Credit < RP.TotalDebit Then 0 Else R.Credit-RP.TotalDebit End,
        R.PaidDate
    From @Tbl R
    Inner Join Temp RP ON R.SNO-1=RP.SNO
)

Select * From Temp
```

[image]

**Spreadsheet sample:** 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FNwzgGxmLiLFS_R5QANnfd16Iw64xhF0gWTc4ZocKsk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what each column should contain? Maybe try a manual run through your sample data in a spreadsheet to get a reference result? CTE itself carries no performance penalty. It's a syntactic sugar to make SQL more readable.

Comment: If you really just need a "previous value" of a "previous value" then all you need is `LAG(..., 2)`. So for `PreviousDebit` you can rewrite `TotalDebit` expression increasing the `LAG` on each value used in calculation.

Comment: @Y.B., I didn't checked with spreadsheet, but i did with sql using CTE. It working but very slow...

Comment: `ISNULL(LAG(T.Debit) OVER (ORDER BY SNO),0)` should actually be `LAG(T.Debit, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY SNO)`.

Comment: Should not `TotalDebit` be a running total? At the moment column name is misleading because the actual value is a sum of only two Debits optionally reduced by one Credit.

Comment: No it is not running total, what i am trying is just detect the previous row's debit amount to Credit, and if the debit is greater than Credit, then update the current rows' Debit. I tried Lag(..1,0) and posted result.

Comment: I can see why recursive CTE can be slow, but I really have no idea what the requirements are, so can not rewrite it in set-oriented logic. Especially puzzling is calculation "reset" from `SNO` 3 to 4.

Comment: ... and the dates in reverse order do not help.

Comment: @Y.B., Thanks for you involvement, i am trying to subtract the debited amount from reciepts table, i create a spreadsheet simulation, look  on it if you have time, https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FNwzgGxmLiLFS_R5QANnfd16Iw64xhF0gWTc4ZocKsk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: So, every time we have historic Credit exceed upcoming Debit, we note a payment out. That has got to re-shuffle the entire lot with every new record arriving. I'll think about it. Out of curiosity, does this have any practical application or is it purely theoretical exercise?

Comment: @Y.B., This is for pratical application (Hire purchase) :) Credit = Paid by customer, Debit = Cheque bounce/Fine. For Cheque bounce, we can remove that Credit easily,other Debits we have to subtract that debited amount from previous credit.

Comment: @Y.B., At every payment(Credit/Debit) we run that query and save it to table, here there is no preformance issues will come, because we are running this query for single invoice. But when printing payment history for particular date for all invoices we have to run the query for all invoices, here we get a huge perfomance issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performance here is suffering from **recursive** CTE. CTE on it's own is just syntactic sugar.

Just for this particular sample data this works without recursion:

```
Declare @Tbl as Table(SNO Int,Credit Money,Debit Money,PaidDate Date)
Insert into @Tbl
SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1,0,12,'7Jan16'), (2,10,0,'6Jan16'), (3,15,0,'5Jan16'), (4,0,5,'4Jan16'), (5,0,3,'3Jan16'), (6,0,2,'2Jan16'), (7,20,0,'1Jan16')) AS X(SNO,Credit,Debit,PaidDate);

With CTE1 As (
    Select *
      , CASE WHEN Credit > 0 THEN LEAD(1 - SIGN(Credit), 1, 1) OVER (ORDER BY SNO) ELSE 0 END As LastCrPerBlock
    From @Tbl
), CTE2 As (
    Select *
      , SUM(LastCrPerBlock) OVER (ORDER BY SNO DESC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) As BlockNumber
    From CTE1
), CTE3 As (
    Select *
      , SUM(Credit - Debit) OVER (PARTITION BY BlockNumber) As BlockTotal
      , SUM(Credit - Debit) OVER (PARTITION BY BlockNumber ORDER BY SNO ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) As BlockRunningTotal
    From CTE2
)
Select SNO, Credit, Debit
  , CASE WHEN BlockRunningTotal < 0 THEN -BlockRunningTotal ELSE 0 END As TotalDebit
  , CASE WHEN BlockRunningTotal > 0 THEN CASE WHEN Credit < BlockRunningTotal THEN Credit ELSE BlockRunningTotal END ELSE 0 END As Amount
  , PaidDate
From CTE3
Order By SNO;
```

This can help evaluate performance, but it will fail if in any block total of `Debit`s exceed total of `Credit`s. If `BlockTotal` is negative then it must be merged with one or several following blocks and that can't be done without iteration or recursion.

In real life I would dump CTE3 into temporary table and cycle over it merging blocks until there are no more negative `BlockTotal`s.

Answer (score 0):

From [Y.B's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5690722/y-b) answer, added recursive CTE to handle if any BlockTotal have negative. Cannot use while loop for recursion because i converted this query to inline table valued function.(Multi-statement table valued function is very slow)

```
Declare @Tbl as Table(ReceiptNo varchar(50),Credit Money,Debit Money,PaidDate Date)
Insert into @Tbl
SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('R1',20,0,'1Jan16'),('R2',0,2,'2Jan16'),('R3',0,3,'3Jan16'),('R4',0,5,'4Jan16'),('R5',10,0,'5Jan16'),('R6',0,1,'6Jan16'),('R7',0,10,'7Jan16')) AS X(ReceiptNo,Credit,Debit,PaidDate);

With Receipts As (
    Select 
        SNO = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY PaidDate Desc),ReceiptNo,Credit,Debit,PaidDate,
        LastCrPerBlock = CASE WHEN Credit > 0 THEN LEAD(1 - SIGN(Credit), 1, 1) OVER (ORDER BY PaidDate DESC) ELSE 0 END
    From @Tbl
), Blocks As (
    Select *
      , SUM(LastCrPerBlock) OVER (ORDER BY SNO DESC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) As BlockNumber
    From Receipts
), BlockTotal As (
    Select *
      , SUM(Credit - Debit) OVER (PARTITION BY BlockNumber) As BlockTotal
      , SUM(Credit - Debit) OVER (PARTITION BY BlockNumber ORDER BY SNO ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) As BlockRunningTotal
    From Blocks
),
ReceiptAmount As (
    Select ReceiptNo,
        Amount = CASE WHEN BlockRunningTotal > 0 THEN CASE WHEN Credit < BlockRunningTotal THEN Credit ELSE BlockRunningTotal END ELSE 0 END,
        Debit = IIF(BlockNumber<>LEAD(BlockNumber) OVER(ORDER BY SNO) and BlockRunningTotal<0,ABS(BlockRunningTotal),0),
        PaidDate
    From BlockTotal
),
FinalReceipt2012 As (
    Select 
        SNO = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY PaidDate Desc),ReceiptNo,Amount,Debit,PaidDate,
        Recur = IIF(Exists(Select Top 1 R1.Amount From ReceiptAmount R1 Where Debit>0),1,0)
    From ReceiptAmount
    Where Amount>0 or Debit>0
),
FinalReceipt As (
    Select * From FinalReceipt2012 Where Recur=0 OR SNO=1
    Union All
    Select
        R.SNO,R.ReceiptNo,
        Amount = Case When R.Amount < RP.Debit Then 0 Else R.Amount-RP.Debit End,
        Debit = Case When R.Amount < RP.Debit Then R.Debit + (RP.Debit-R.Amount) Else R.Debit End,
        R.PaidDate,0 As Recur
    From FinalReceipt2012 R 
    Inner Join FinalReceipt RP ON R.SNO=RP.SNO+1
    Where R.Recur=1
)

Select ReceiptNo,Amount,PaidDate From FinalReceipt Where Amount>0
```

**Input:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]